# Hide elements by clicking outside

Tags: jquery

I have some problems hiding my elements which are in an array. I put all elements to hide in an array which I loop through with `.each()`. But somehow the elements do not disappear :/

Here is my code:

```
$('html').bind("click", function(e) {
            var hiddenElements = ['#loginContainer'];

            $.each(hiddenElements, function(index, value) {
                $(value).hide();
            });
        });
```

Comment: Could we see your HTML? I think you may be using the wrong selector.

Comment: What you have should work: http://jsfiddle.net/LyqhJ/

Comment: Why don't you just do: `$('#loginContainer').hide();` ?

Comment: That's probably not your real code as it's working fine. Post real code and we'll help you find the real problem.

Comment: Its my real code... I guess the problem was the HTML code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `each` loop you can even try this.

```
   $('html').bind("click", function(e) {
        var hiddenElements = ['#loginContainer'];
        $(hiddenElements.join(',')).hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some custom event-type'ish plugin. For instance

```
$.fn.outside = function(ename, cb){
    return this.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            self = this;

        $(document).bind(ename, function tempo(e){
            if(e.target !== self && !$.contains(self, e.target)){
                cb.apply(self, [e]);
                if(!self.parentNode) $(document.body).unbind(ename, tempo);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

and then use that like

```
$('#ElementToHide').outside('click', function(e) {
    $(this).hide();
});
```